# Автоматический вход на сайт без участия юзера

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые кодеры. В общем загвоздка в том, что не могу сделать автоматический вход на сайт, не нажимая кнопки вход. При входе на сайт юзер получает логин и пароль, всё это дело записывает в базу mysql, но как сделать, чтобы не нужно было вводить эти пароль и логин в саму логин панель, а скрыть её и автоматом входить без нажатия на кнопку войти. Помогите разобраться...

Comment: создать куку, если кука существует то авторизируем иначе показываем форму

Comment: кука есть. Мне нужен сам метод именно код авто авторизации!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При первом входе устанавливаешь какую-нибудь куку с помощью setcookie, третьим аргументом функции устанавливаешь время жизни, скажем, две недели.

```
setcookie("willkommen", $value, time()+3600*24*14);
```

Если в течении 2х недель зашел, устанавливаешь куку заново снова на две недели от текущей дату. Если не появлялся больше 2х недель нехай вводит пароль заново

Answer (score 0):

В сессию записывай, не знаю, может тут кто-то скажет использовать куки, но я не фанат, и я так ни делаю.

Comment: Сессия живет меньше. Тут дело не в фанат-не фанат, а в различии инструментов и целей.